# jQuery: fadeOut <div> element with with a close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a dashboard UI where I want to be able to close some panels. I tried several ways to use the "this" keyword to avoid hard coding everything but couldn't figure it out. I'm sure there has to be a much more effective way to do what I did but I did achieve my goal.

Can anyone enlighten me on what I could do different?

HTML:

```
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-5" id="div1">
   <div class="cs-header">
      <p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close1"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></p>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex hic ipsam voluptates! Harum odio porro temporibus nisi, amet maiores, rem nostrum sit vitae inventore officiis vel eius soluta atque velit.</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" id="div2">
   <div class="cs-header">
      <p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close2"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></p>
   </div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore numquam, perferendis impedit, dolores quibusdam blanditiis id ipsum delectus minus eligendi repudiandae amet, velit voluptatum perspiciatis pariatur dicta aut mollitia cupiditate.</p> 
</div>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-centered" id="div3">
   <div class="cs-header">
      <p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close3"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></p>
   </div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut doloremque magnam quo quisquam, nesciunt, excepturi recusandae harum nisi? Ipsum vel explicabo ab, saepe sed animi ex quas. Voluptate, dicta, et.</p> 
</div>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-centered" id="div4">
   <div class="cs-header">
      <p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close4"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></p>
   </div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis dolorum dicta molestias velit, quaerat cum reiciendis commodi rem alias maiores, quis optio quas quasi. Dolorem magnam laborum, nesciunt velit nobis?</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-centered" id="div5">
   <div class="cs-header">
      <p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close5"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></p>
   </div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae est quibusdam, repellendus quae ullam fugiat quos illum enim sit sunt itaque fugit alias ducimus soluta nihil, tenetur laudantium id, numquam.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div').on('click', '#close1', function () {
            $('#div1').fadeOut();
        });

        $('div').on('click', '#close2', function () {
            $('#div2').fadeOut();
        });

        $('div').on('click', '#close3', function () {
            $('#div3').fadeOut();
        });

        $('div').on('click', '#close4', function () {
            $('#div4').fadeOut();
        });

        $('div').on('click', '#close5', function () {
            $('#div5').fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example where the user clicks on `.btn-close` and then fades out the closest section. It's much easier to bind an event to an class instead of several id's.

Since we're listening to an event we can use `$(this)` within the event listener. It will return the element that was clicked (in this example the anchor). When we got the clicked element we can use `[.closest][1]` to find the parent element based on class. And then we can use `fadeOut()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Listen to clicks on btn-close
        $('.content-section').on('click', '.btn-close', function () {
            // Get closest content-section and fade it out.
            // $(this) will be the anchor with the class btn-close.
            $(this).closest('.content-section').fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-5" id="div1">
                   <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close1"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex hic ipsam voluptates! Harum odio porro temporibus nisi, amet maiores, rem nostrum sit vitae inventore officiis vel eius soluta atque velit.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" id="div2">
                   <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close2">X<i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></p></div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore numquam, perferendis impedit, dolores quibusdam blanditiis id ipsum delectus minus eligendi repudiandae amet, velit voluptatum perspiciatis pariatur dicta aut mollitia cupiditate.</p> 
                </div>
                <div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-centered" id="div3">
                   <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close3"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut doloremque magnam quo quisquam, nesciunt, excepturi recusandae harum nisi? Ipsum vel explicabo ab, saepe sed animi ex quas. Voluptate, dicta, et.</p> 
                </div>
                <div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-centered" id="div4">
                   <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close4"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis dolorum dicta molestias velit, quaerat cum reiciendis commodi rem alias maiores, quis optio quas quasi. Dolorem magnam laborum, nesciunt velit nobis?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-centered" id="div5">
                   <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close5"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae est quibusdam, repellendus quae ullam fugiat quos illum enim sit sunt itaque fugit alias ducimus soluta nihil, tenetur laudantium id, numquam.</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate it. Still a long road ahead to master this skill but your reply was very clear and I understood the mechanics of it which is great. Thanks again for the help. I knew there was a way but couldn't figure it out, I wasn't aware of the closest method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
        $('.btn-close').click(function){
            $(this).parent().fadeOut();
        });
});
```

Comment: I've tried something similar to this but this doesn't fade the object since it the parent div isn't the div I want to close. It would fade the header div instead on my attempts.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13227261)

Comment: ahh, apologies. I didn't take a hard look at the HTML structure. I'll provide more context in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('div a[id^="close"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var idNumber = this.id.split('').pop();
    $(this).closest('#div' + idNumber).fadeOut();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-5" id="div1">
    <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close1"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex hic ipsam voluptates! Harum odio porro temporibus nisi, amet maiores, rem nostrum sit vitae inventore officiis vel eius soluta atque velit.</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" id="div2">
    <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close2"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore numquam, perferendis impedit, dolores quibusdam blanditiis id ipsum delectus minus eligendi repudiandae amet, velit voluptatum perspiciatis pariatur dicta aut mollitia cupiditate.</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-centered" id="div3">
    <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close3"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut doloremque magnam quo quisquam, nesciunt, excepturi recusandae harum nisi? Ipsum vel explicabo ab, saepe sed animi ex quas. Voluptate, dicta, et.</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-centered" id="div4">
    <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close4"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis dolorum dicta molestias velit, quaerat cum reiciendis commodi rem alias maiores, quis optio quas quasi. Dolorem magnam laborum, nesciunt velit nobis?</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-centered" id="div5">
    <div class="cs-header"><p>Header<a href="#" class="btn-close right" id="close5"><i class="fa fa-close">X</i></a></p></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae est quibusdam, repellendus quae ullam fugiat quos illum enim sit sunt itaque fugit alias ducimus soluta nihil, tenetur laudantium id, numquam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help and feedback. It is really appreciated. Regards, Rod